# Is there a maximum on the number of search results returned (using the SO API)?

Tags: support, api, search

I was trying to do statistics on post from some not-too-popular tags like `matlab`, using the [search method](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/search).  It appears that it will never return a `total` larger than 2000.  Is this a hard limit that cannot be lifted?  Is it possible to get the question count even if it's larger than 2000?  If yes, is it possible to get the data for all questions as well?

**EDIT:**

An example query: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=matlab&page=1&pagesize=1
Unfortunately it gives an error 500 at this moment, but later you should be able to see that it returns `total = 2000`, which is only about half the total number number of `matlab`-tagged questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a `/search` is quite expensive, so we do cap the returns at 2000.  Note that this limit is **not** contractual, and subject to change (it has been pretty stable for a while, but we're seeing thousands of new posts a day... we may encounter a tipping point in the future).

In this case, if you want all questions tagged `matlab` [this](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?tagged=matlab) is a better query.  If you're not using `nottagged` or `intitle` then `/search` is probably  bad fit for you.